# Pseudo-affine functions that are not affine

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Can any one please give a hint for finding the solution of the following question?
I can't imagine such a function should exist.

**Definition**: Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of a linear space. We say that a map $\psi\in \mathbb{R}^S$ is pseudo-affine if $\psi (\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=\lambda \psi(x)+(1-\lambda)\psi(y)$ for all $0\leq \lambda\leq 1$ and $x,y\in S$ with  $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y \in S$

(a) Give an example of a nonempty subset $S\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a pseudo-affine $\psi\in \mathbb{R}^S$ such that is not affine.

Here, an affine function is defined by the following.

**Definition**: A real map $\psi\in\mathbb{R}^S$ is called affine if

> $\psi(\sum_{x\in A}\lambda(x)x)=\sum \lambda(x)\psi(x)$

for any $A\in P(S)$ (the class of all nonempty finite subsets of $S$), and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^A$ such that $\sum \lambda(x)=1$ and $\sum \lambda(x)x\in S$

Comment: Consider the vertices of a rectangle.

Comment: Daniel Fischer thanks for replying!!!

Comment: But wouldn't that be affine?Since we need to think of a linear combination that the projection is contained in the space (S)

Comment: I don't understand that comment.

Comment: So suppose psi=x1+x2 is the psuedo affine function and let it be defined on the closed unit rectangle in R^2.   Then some affine combination of the elements in the rectangle (such as (100000,100000) ) does not have a projection, but it is also not included in the original rectangle.  Therefore we cannot use this example to examine if psi is affine or not

Comment: Maybe I should upload the definition of affine functions, just in case

Comment: How many points suffice to completely determine an affine function? (On subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.)